# Laravel API returns "500 Internal Server Error" when requested by other apps

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Using a laravel API for testing, when using Fiddler or Postman it returns 200.

[image: Postman result]

But after I try to access from another web application, the request fails.

[image: My app result]

API's login function.

```
    public function login(Request $request){
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->all()['email'], 'password' => $request->all()['password']])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
        $success['user'] = $user;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

Function on another web app:

```
public function req()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('post', 'http://testapi/api/login', [
            'form_params' =>
                ['email' => 'oleg@mail.ru',
                    'password' => '123456']
        ]
    );

    $r = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Through trial and error, I realized that a token is not generated, I cannot understand why this happens, because with the help of Postman and Fiddler everything works out.

Execution reaches this line and everything falls.

```
 $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
```

Knowledgeable people, please help! I'll be very grateful!

Comment: can you share your route

Comment: its because of missing csrf token and I am looking for a solution too, hope I will find out.

Comment: Had the same problem, try this.
`php artisan passport:install`
If you refreshed your database you need to install passport again probably.

Answer (score 1):

Is this web app running on another domain than the Laravel app? If so, you might need to look into CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) support.
This seems to be a popular package for CORS support https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

I hope this might help you.

EDIT:

You have a space in between `$user->createToken('MyApp')->` and  `accessToken`

like: `$user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken` should be `$user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken`. Is that fixed in your code?

Same for this piece in the return statement `$this-> successStatus` should be `$this->successStatus`. Also, is successStatus defined?

If this is not the issue, try dooing a `dd()` on  `$user->createToken('MyApp')` and see if that returns anything. If so, check if there is an `accessToken` property present.

Comment: I installed CORS, but still the same error 500. The request comes to me, and the result returns (to the string with the formation of the token). I can not understand why this is so, with the help of Postman everything works, but not from another application. Maybe there is some problem in the guzzle? But again, the data goes away and the user is successfully authenticated, but the token is no longer forming.

Comment: I checked your question again. I added some other option to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when your method is not equal to the received method.
The submission method should be a `post` like `postman`, so the error does not happen.
Also, to display the information in the form of json,the value in the recipe header itself must be  `Accept` should be equal to `Application/json` .

Comment: if I return the user before generating the token everything is done normally

Comment: those condition if(Auth::attempt...) is satisfied

Comment: You must submit a request using the POST Method, not the GET Method

Comment: Please indicate in the code what I did wrong. I just use the post request.

Answer (score 0):

Its because its protected by csrf token, here is solution while you are in testing env.

Comment this line

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

in app\Http\Kernel.php